# How to set dial to maximum in angular gauge chart when value is more than maximum?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion chart library. In that I am using `Angular Gauge` chart for my report. I'm facing issue with dial which is automatically set by fusion chart library based on dial value we are passing to it. What the issue is when I pass value more than maximum limit, fusion chart sets dial pointer to 0. I want pointer to the end as if I passed maximum value.

If I add one condition before passing data to dial value like if it beyond the maximum value then overwrite it with maximum value then it works. Pointer will be set as expected but the value which it showing will not be what I want. it will be maximum value all the time.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nVm2/68/)

You can see. when I pass `101`, it sets pointer to 0. I want to set at 100 however I want to display value as 101 only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation with the Angular Gauge and is reported and currently being fixed. The work around would be to increase the range in ColorRange section.

```
    "colorRange": {
        "color": [
            {
                "minValue": "0",
                "maxValue": "50",
                "code": "#e44a00"
            },
            {
                "minValue": "50",
                "maxValue": "75",
                "code": "#f8bd19"
            },
            {
                "minValue": "75",
                "maxValue": "110",
                "code": "#6baa01"
            }
        ]
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nVm2/69/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But 101 value is just an example. It's dynamic and it can be 150, 200, 240 or any value so It can't be fit with your solution.

Comment: Yes, and that is why I mentioned that this is a limitation.